# How to categorize a large integer vector efficiently in R

Tags: r, categories

I've a large integer vector (part of the data shown below):

```
a <- c(0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,4,4,7,7,7,35,50,50, 200,200,500,500,500, 2500,2501,2502,2502)
```

I would like to create another vector (vector b) that categorizes vector a values into bins. The category values should be 1 for vector a values 0 - 6, 2 for 7 - 13, 3 for 14 - 20 ...

I know I can use the dplyr `case_when()` function to mutate but when the data is big it may not be efficient.

Comment: Try with `findInterval` `findInterval(a, c(6, 13, 20))`

Comment: I would try `cut` and see if that works, too. `cut(a, c(-Inf, 0, 6, 13, 30, Inf), labels =  FALSE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to categorize numeric data into ranges with a numeric output value is the `findInterval` function. Examples:

```
> a <- c(0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,4,4,7,7,7,35,50,50, 200,200,500,500,500, 2500,2501,2502,2502)
> findInterval( a, c(0, 6, 12, 18, 24))
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
> findInterval( a, 6^(0:6))
 [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 5
> 6^(0:6)
[1]     1     6    36   216  1296  7776 46656
```

Note that the value returned for items below the min value in the second argument is 0 and the value for items above the max is the length of the `vec` (i.e breaks) vector. The intervals are left-closed, right-open, which is the opposite of how the `cut` function behaves (unless changed by parameters).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I know I can use findInterval too but when the data is big, let's say in thousands, listing the cutoff points may be time consuming. I was thinking a for loop where vector a values  start from 0 with increment i = 6 and vector b starts from 1 and increment j = 1 but I was not successful (I'm new to R programming). Thanks again.

Comment: The second example above was intended to show how an R integer sequence could be used although it created a geometric progression. Perhaps you need to use some version of `seq` for an arithmetic series say `seq(from=0, to=10^7, by=6)` to supply the `vec` (breaks) value. I didn't know what `a` and `b` were supposed to be in your comment, however. In your original question `a` seemed to be the vector to be classified, whereas in the comment it appeared to be the breaks values.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much! That solves my problem.